# Is there anything wrong with this pattern for a JS library?

Tags: coding-style, javascript

I admittedly know little about the inner workings of javascript, but need to make a library and would like to learn (hence asking here). I understand using the closure and exporting to window to not pollute the global namespace, but beyond that it confuses me a bit.

```
(function() {
    var Drop = window.Drop = function() { 

        var files = [];

        var add = function(word) {
              files.push(word);    
              return files;
        }

        return {
            files: files,
            add: add
        }
    }
})()


// All of these seem to be the same?
var a = Drop();
var b = new Drop();
var c = new Drop;

// Each has their own state which is what I want.
a.add("file1");
b.add("file2");
c.add("file3");
```

- Why are all three ways of "initializing" Drop the same?
- What exactly gives them the ability to have their own state?
- Is there an alternative to the return syntax to export those functions on Drop?
- Is there just a flat out better best practice way of creating a self contained library like this?

I have searched around the net, but have found very little consistency on this subject.

Comment: You probably want to read about "javascript closures".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The first way (`Drop()`) just calls the function as normal, so `this` is the global object (`window` in browser environments). It does its stuff and then returns an object, as you'd expect.

   The second way (`new Drop()`) creates a new `Drop` object and executes the constructor with `this` set to that object. You do not, however, use `this` anywhere and return an object created from an object literal, so the `Drop` object is discarded and the object literal returned instead.

   The third way (`new Drop`) is semantically the same as the second; it is only a syntactic difference.
2. They all have their own state because each time you call `Drop`, it has its own set of local variables distinct from the local variables of any other call to `Drop`.
3. You could transform your code to use the normal `new` syntax and prototypes. This has a few advantages: namely, you only create the `add` function once rather than one for each `Drop` call. Your modified code might look like this:

   ```
   function Drop() {
       this.files = [];
   }
   Drop.prototype.add = function(word) {
       this.files.push(word);
       return this.files;
   };
   ```

   By doing this, though, you lose being able to call it without `new`. There is, however, a workaround: You can add this as the first line inside `function Drop`:

   ```
   if(!(this instanceof Drop)) {
       return new Drop();
   }
   ```

   Since when you call it with `new`, `this` will be a `Drop`, and when you call it without `new`, `this` will be something other than a `Drop`, you can see if `this` is a `Drop`, and if it is, continue initializing; otherwise, reinvoke it with `new`.

   There is also another semantic difference. Consider the following code:

   ```
   var drop = new Drop();
   var adder = drop.add;
   adder(someFile);
   ```

   Your code will work here. The prototype-based code will not, since `this` will be the global object, not `drop`. This, too, has a workaround: somewhere in your constructor, you can do this:

   ```
   this.add = this.add.bind(this);
   ```

   Of course, if your library's consumers are not going to pull the function out of the object, you won't need to do this. Furthermore, you might need to shim `Function.prototype.bind` for browsers that don't have it.
4. No. It's all a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

- *Why are all three ways of "initializing" Drop the same?*

```
// All of these seem to be the same?
var a = Drop();
var b = new Drop();
var c = new Drop;
```

When you use `new` in JavaScript to invoke a function, the value of `this` inside the function becomes the new object.

But the reason they're the same in your case is that you're not using `this` at all. You're making a separate object using *object literal* syntax, and returning it instead, so the `new` has no impact.

---

- *What exactly gives them the ability to have their own state?*

Because each function invocation makes a new object, each object is entirely different for each invocation.

The functions assigned to the object are recreated in each `Drop` invocation, and therefore create a closure over the enclosing variable scope. As such, the `files` array of each invocation is continuously accessible to the functions made in each respective invocation.

---

- *Is there an alternative to the return syntax to export those functions on Drop?*

Yes. Assign the functions and array to `this`, and remove the `return` statement. But that will *require* the use of `new`. Alternatively, put the functions on the `.prototype` object of `Drop`, and they'll be shared among all instances made using `new`, but keep the array assigned to `this` in the constructor so that it's not shared.

For the prototyped functions to reference the array, they would  use `this.files`.

---

- *Is there just a flat out better best practice way of creating a self contained library like this?*

JavaScript is very flexible. There are many ways to approach a single problem, each with its own advantages/disadvantages. Generally it'll boil down to taking advantage of *closures*, of *prototypal inheritance*, or some combination of both.

---

Here's a full prototypal inheritance version. Also, the outer `(function() {})()` isn't being used, so I'm going to add a variable to take advantage of it.

```
(function() {
    var totalObjects = 0; // visible only to functions created in this scope

    var Drop = window.Drop = function() { 
        this.files = [];
        this.serialNumber = totalObjects++;
    }

    Drop.prototype.add = function(word) {
        this.files.push(word);    
        return this.files;
    };
})();
```